# wp_insert_post doesn't run plugins

Tags: wordpress

I made a wordpress plugin which posts on your behalf . I use wp_insert_post() function to do so , but it ignores the other plugins which are supposed to run when you add a new article. One of those  is NextScript's snap plugin. Auto Post Thumbnail doesn't run also. Anyone had this problem before?

Comment: May be this one is relate - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/30034
Also suggestion to ask @ http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ for WP issues. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On success, `wp_insert_post` returns the post ID, which you can use to further process the newly inserted content, e.g. in the case of Auto Post Thumbnail:

```
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $args );

if( function_exists( 'apt_publish_post' ) )
    apt_publish_post( $post_id );
```

Comment: Thank you! I used apt_publish_post() along with nxs_doPublishToFB() and it worked great. Thanks again!